# Store file to S3 could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel

I get an exception when i try to store this file to S3

> Object of class Maatwebsite\Excel\Writers\LaravelExcelWriter could not
>   be converted to string

Here my code :

```
$file = Excel::create('' . $date . '' , function($excel) use ($licencies) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($licencies)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($licencies);

        });

    });

    Storage::disk('s3')->put($file , 'upload');

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $fileName = $date . '.xls';

    $fileContent = Excel::create($fileName , function($excel) use ($licencies) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($licencies) {
            $sheet->fromArray($licencies);
        });
    })->string('xls');

    Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, $fileContent);
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I wonder why this method is omitted from any documentation.